# Excel: Array formula inside another formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

[image]

`B` column copies values from column `A` and if it is not the minimum value in the given range, then adds 1, else it is left as it is with: `=IF(NOT($A2=MIN($A$2:$A$7)),$A2+1,$A2)`

`C2` finds the cell with the minimum non-zero value from the range `A2:A7` with `=MIN(IF(A2:A7>0,A2:A7))` (with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>).

Is it possible to use this array formula as a sub-expression in another formula? Say I want to ADD 1 if the value in `A2:A7` is NOT the minimum no-zero value?

So in the above example nothing will be added to `A6`. And `D2:D7` values will be:

```
6    
5    
4    
3    
1    
1
```

Comment: You mean to say that, you want to combine both the above shown formulas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it's even possible to use that particular array formula as a sub-expression in another formula.

However, there's a work-around. You just need a **non**-array formula that works out the minimum non-zero value.

Such a formula can be created with the `SMALL()` function:

```dart
=SMALL($A$2:$A$7,COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,0)+1)
```

The leads to the working solution

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

where the formula in  `D2` is just the formula in `B2` with the `MIN()` function replaced with the `SMALL()` function:

```dart
=IF(NOT($A2=SMALL($A$2:$A$7,COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,0)+1)),$A2+1,$A2)
```

Note that this formula is *not* array entered!

---

I prefer writing these types of formulas refactored so they don't use a `NOT()` and the reference is outside the `IF()`:

```dart
=$A2+IF($A2=SMALL($A$2:$A$7,COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,0)+1),0,1)
```

My real favourite factorisation, though, is this:

```dart
=$A2+($A2<>SMALL($A$2:$A$7,COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,0)+1))
```

Unfortunately, a lot of folks find that hacky and hard to read, so I tend not to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there seems to exist a functionality for this, in case someone stumbles upon the same problem as I did.

Making use of the spill range functionality, you just need to append the '#' char to the address of the first cell of the spill range you want to use as part of some function, e.g. 'A1#'.

Answer (score 0):

*Answer posted by @RobinCTS inspired me to do the useful corrections in both of your exciting formulas.*

[image]

Your first formula should be written like shown below in Cell C2 to **find minimum non-zero.**

```
{=MIN(IF(A2:A7>0,A2:A7,A2+1))}
```

In Cell D2 write this array formula to **add 1 if not minimum non-zero** & fill it down.

```
{=IF(A2<>MIN(IF(A2:A7>0,A2:A7,A2+1)),A2+1,A2)}
```

**N.B.** *Both above written formula are an array formula so finish both with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.*